# Removing noise from an image but I could not store words in the image, MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, octave, noise-reduction

I need to clear noises from my image, The input image is :

[image]

To do that, I've applied some filter operations and after all, I've got the following image :

[image]

However, as you see, the words (LIBERTE,EGALITE,FRATERNITE)were gone after the operations that I`ve applied, is there anyone who can tell me what should I do at this point ?

Comment: The final image should be similar to this one : 

http://prntscr.com/54lqtp

Comment: Maybe you should show us what you have done (code please) instead of ***Ive applied some filter operations***

Comment: @drescherjm yea of course, sorry about it my mistake, Actually I did not do too much things, just seperate the image into rgb channels and applied median filter to each of the channels seperately.

Comment: Try various sizes of your median filter.  The larger your median filter is, the more obscure the text will look.